# Maven build throwing an error "File not exists"

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, maven, maven-plugin

I have created a Maven project but when I run the maven build command, it is throwing the error below.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\scala-SDK\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\17\0\.cp\
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:264)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Configurator.configure(Configurator.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.configure(Launcher.java:131)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Reinstall the sdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that the path of

```
E:\scala-SDK\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\17\0\.cp\
```

does not exist. Possibilities:

## The user might lack privileges

Make sure that the user whom is running the Maven build has proper access rights to the given path, try to log in with the user and to navigate to the given path. If there is a privilege problem, then you won't be able to navigate to that path.

## The file might have been (re)moved

If that's the case, you will just need to find out whether the path has changed. If so, apply the changes on your build configuration. If everything fails, you might need to reinstall dependencies, like the SDK.

Comment: Yes, I don’t have privileges to access the file.